# Mounting a network volume from OS X App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to mount a network volume in a OS X App.

I get it to work using the `FSMountServerVolume` function which is deprecated. The documentation says "To mount a network volume, use NetFSMountURLAsync instead". But when I try to use this function I get the following error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _NetFSMountURLSync  
Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ammmlfwhvlfxkdburfmzioformdn/Build/Products/Debug/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS

dyld: Symbol not found: _NetFSMountURLSync
Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ammmlfwhvlfxkdburfmzioformdn/Build/Products/Debug/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
```

Did I forget anything? I imported the NetFS Framework.

Comment: On what version of OSX does this error happen?

Comment: The error happens on version 10.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like `NetFSMountURLSync()` etc where introduced in 10.8.

From [NetFS Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_8/NetFS.html):

```
Added AsyncRequestID
Added NetFSMountURLAsync()
Added NetFSMountURLBlock
Added NetFSMountURLCancel()
Added NetFSMountURLSync()
Added #def kNAUIOptionAllowUI
Added #def kNAUIOptionForceUI
Added #def kNAUIOptionKey
Added #def kNAUIOptionNoUI
Added #def kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey
```

Therefore you are going to have to use the "old way" in 10.7 and below and the "new way" in 10.8 and above.  This means making the `NetFS.framework` *optional* rather than *required* and the need to perform various runtime checks to see which API you need to use.